# Android error on changing app icon using <activity-alias>

Tags: android, kotlin

**Error**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.fireframe.noxwallpapers, PID: 18833
                                                                                                    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.fireframe.noxwallpapers/com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2249)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1878)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5743)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:780)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5701)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:761)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6199)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6166)
                                                                                                        at com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.SplashScreen.endSplash$lambda$0(SplashScreen.kt:151)
                                                                                                        at com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.SplashScreen.$r8$lambda$L59SC2q6eERHvWVIWOUzibvW7Lg(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.SplashScreen$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
```

**Mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoxWallpapers"
        tools:replace="android:fullBackupContent"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <!-- Launcher activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- MainActivity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <!-- No need for category DEFAULT in the intent-filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- MainActivityPremium alias -->
        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivityPremium"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_golden_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_golden_launcher_round"
            android:targetActivity="com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivity">
            <!-- No need for category DEFAULT in the intent-filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity
            android:name=".subscription.SubscriptionActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".autoChangeWallpaper.AutoChangeWallpaperActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".viewWallpaper.CollectionWallpapers"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".CollectionsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".CollectionWallpapersActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".CategoryWallpapersActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".CreditsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".viewWallpaper.SpecialWallpapers"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".viewWallpaper.FeaturedWallpapers"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".viewWallpaper.CategoryWallpapers"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".viewWallpaper.PremiumWallpapers"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".viewWallpaper.SearchWallpapers"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".OnBoardingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/adMob_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="General" />

        <service
            android:name=".notification.NotificationService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firbase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Main Activity**

```
        //Admob
        //initializing
        if ((subPerfHelper.getStatus() == "premium") || (subPerfHelper.getStatus() == "semi-premium")) {
            binding.bannerAd1.visibility = View.GONE
            if (subPerfHelper.getIconStatus() == "default"){
                changeIconToPremium()
                subPerfHelper.setIconStatus("premium")
            }
        } else {
            if (subPerfHelper.getIconStatus() == "premium"){
                changeIconToDefault()
                subPerfHelper.setIconStatus("default")
            }
            MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
            // banner ads
            val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
            binding.bannerAd1.loadAd(adRequest)
            binding.bannerAd1.adListener = object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                    binding.bannerAd1.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                    binding.bannerAd1.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                }
            }
        }


private fun changeIconToPremium() {
        //Disable default icon
        val packageManager = packageManager
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            ComponentName(this,"com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivity"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )

        //Enable golden icon
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            ComponentName(this,"com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivityPremium"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )

    }

    private fun changeIconToDefault() {

        //Disable golden icon
        val packageManager = packageManager
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            ComponentName(this,"com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivityPremium"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )

        //Enable default icon
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            ComponentName(this,"com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivity"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )

    }
```

I need that if user is premium or seim-premium then changeIconToPremium() function to be called else changeIconToDefault() to be called. Please help me fix it...

I have tried many way but not able to fix the error.  It awalys throws activitynotfoundexception error my launcher activity is .SplashScreen so even after changing icon launcher activity should be .SplashScreen

Answer (score 0):

com.fireframe.noxwallpapers/com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.MainActivity}

remove com.fireframe.noxwallpapers. Like your SplashScreen. Your MainActivity activity class cant be found.

```
    <!-- MainActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

And stop use activities after MainActivity, use fragments for all pages.